# Getting 403 error during GET request from Java application

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, get

I am trying to do a GET request with JAVA client using `RestTemplate` library, resulting in following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

When I am trying to hit the same URL by command line it is working fine. Posting the cURL command and Java code snippet here.

**cURL :**

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer ${TOKEN}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://xxxx-xxxx-xxxx {"key":"value"}
```

**JAVA snippet :**

```
String URL="https://xyz";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

//setting up the required headers
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("body",headers);

//get request
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

**P.S - Is the issue because of the URL being a HTTPS one instead of HTTP ?**

Comment: "Is the issue because of the URL being a HTTPS one instead of HTTP" - probably, how should we know as you haven't posted the URL you use in Java.

Comment: URL is `https://xyz`, can't post the full URL because of security reasons.

Comment: Can you try the curl verbose command using `-v` to get the complete request details and try to match it with the one generated by java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the user agent header, try and let us know if it works.

```
String URL="https://xyz";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

//setting up the required headers
headers.setAccept(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
//settting user agent
headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");

headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessToken);

HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>("body",headers);

//get request
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
```

Comment: Hi, now getting `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized`.

Comment: which means you have invalid accessToken, you need to get a valid token.